# Chrome extension cant connect to jar using native messages

Tags: java, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

im trying to write very basic (for now) chrome exstension that communicates with execuable jar but it seems i can't get even a connection between them. Chrome debug says that port is disconnected  and i have no idea why and cant find solution that work...

My extension is composed of 4 files:

some icon.png

### manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Getting started example",
  "description": "Native",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "nativeMessaging"
  ]
}
```

### popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Moj extension</title>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: "Segoe UI", "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, sans-serif;
        font-size: 100%;
        width: 300px
      }
      #status {
        /* avoid an excessively wide status text */
        white-space: pre;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        overflow: hidden;
        max-width: 400px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <button id="butt" type="button">Click Me!</button>
    <div id="status">test</div>
    <div id="response"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

### popup.js

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    document.getElementById("butt").addEventListener("click", function(){
        var port = chrome.runtime.connectNative('pl.splaw.nativejavaapp');
        port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
            console.log("Received" + msg);
            document.getElementById('response').text(msg);
        });
        port.onDisconnect.addListener(function() {
            console.log("Disconnected");
        });
        port.postMessage({ text: "test" });
    });
});
```

---

### Java

Java class looks like this:

```
package pl.splaw.nativejavaapp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NativeApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("STARTED");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        try {
            System.in.available();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return;
        }
        String fullMessage = "";
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            fullMessage += line;
            if (fullMessage.equalsIgnoreCase("test")) {
                System.out.write(getBytes("TEST OK".length()));
                System.out.write("TEST OK".getBytes());
            } else {
                System.out.write(getBytes("TEST ERROR".length()));
                System.out.write("TEST ERROR".getBytes());
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    public static byte[] getBytes(int length) {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
        bytes[0] = (byte) (length & 0xFF);
        bytes[1] = (byte) ((length >> 8) & 0xFF);
        bytes[2] = (byte) ((length >> 16) & 0xFF);
        bytes[3] = (byte) ((length >> 24) & 0xFF);
        return bytes;
    }
}
```

### manifest.json

next to jar file:

```
{
    "name": "pl.splaw.nativejavaapp",
    "description": "Test native app",
    "path": "C:\\PROJEKTY\\Chrome native and extension\\native\\native jar i manifest\\NativeApp-jar-with-dependencies.jar",
    "type": "stdio",
    "allowed_origins": [
        "chrome-extension://ID_of_my_extension_when_added_to_chrome/"
    ]
}
```

---

I have run command to add registry key like this:

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\pl.splaw.nativejavaapp" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "C:\PROJEKTY\Chrome native and extension\native\native jar i manifest\manifest.json" /f
```

---

Now when i opn extension in Chrome and click button nothing happens besides that in console is error

> Uncaught Error: Attempting to use a disconnected port object

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I think the `while` loop should be unconditional: `while(true)` because `sc.hasNext()` will only be true when a message was actually sent so your loop isn't working. IIRC there was a similar/duplicate question last month, I can't find it right now.

Comment: i changed to while(true) but didnt solve it...

I did some more debuging and it seems that connection starts but my java is failing on "System.in.available()"  (Some IOException but message is in Polish so im not sure if i'll translate it correctly but more or less it says "Incorrect access")... but i dont know why?
when i run jar from commandline it works fine but from chrome "System.in" is "not working"... WTF?

Comment: Not sure chrome can start `.jar` directly (or maybe it starts without the console as a window-app). Try creating a simple `.bat` file launcher instead with this code inside `@java "%~dp0\NativeApp-jar-with-dependencies.jar` or something like that.

Comment: i tried with simple batch file but still didnt do the trick... console just dont want to stay open... i gues writing in different language will be only solution...